# Inserting data into two tables from Form

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data from a form into two different tables using the following code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $date = addslashes ($_POST['date']);
}
else
{
   $date = $_POST['date'];
}

$num_P1 = $_POST['num_P1'];
$num_P2 = $_POST['num_P2'];
$num_P3 = $_POST['num_P3'];
$num_P4 = $_POST['num_P4'];
$num_P5 = $_POST['num_P5'];
$num_B1 = $_POST['num_B1'];
$num_B2 = $_POST['num_B2'];
$jackpot = $_POST['jackpot'];
$jackpot2 = $_POST ['jackpot']*0.842799998;
$jp_code = $_POST['jp_code'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO euromillions ".
       "(date, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, B1, B2, jackpot, jp_code) ".
       "VALUES('$date',$num_P1,$num_P2,$num_P3,$num_P4,$num_P5,$num_B1, $num_B2, $jackpot, $jp_code)".
       "INSERT INTO euromillions_uk ".
       "(date, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, B1, B2, jackpot, jp_code) ".
       "VALUES('$date',$num_P1,$num_P2,$num_P3,$num_P4,$num_P5,$num_B1, $num_B2, $jackpot2, $jp_code)";

mysql_select_db('lottotools');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
```

I am getting an error the following error message:

Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO euromillions_uk (date, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, B1, B2, jackpot, jp_code)' at line 1

Can somebody please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: `date` is a reserved word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it separate query and execute

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO euromillions 
       (date, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, B1, B2, jackpot, jp_code) 
       VALUES('$date',$num_P1,$num_P2,$num_P3,$num_P4,$num_P5,$num_B1, $num_B2, $jackpot, $jp_code)";

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO euromillions_uk 
        (date, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, B1, B2, jackpot, jp_code) 
        VALUES('$date',$num_P1,$num_P2,$num_P3,$num_P4,$num_P5,$num_B1, $num_B2, $jackpot2, $jp_code)";


$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine two insert queries. you need to run them seperately as 2 insert queries. `mysql libraries` only execute one query at a time.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL error messages always indicate exactly where the parser found the error. This isn't an insert error, this is a syntax error.

In your case it is with the start of the second statement. You can't have a second statement in mysql_query queries, no matter whether they are inserts, selects, or anything else.

You will have to separate the two statements and run them separately.